# State won't stay updated

Tags: reactjs

After I use `setState` in `getClients()`, the state `clientOptions` is showed correctly. But when I try to pass it on to a child component it is an empty array. I've tried logging it again after `componentDidMount` and there it seems that the state `clientOptions` is resetted to its original state (`[]`). Sorry if this seems like a noob question, I'am pretty new to react.

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clientFilter: 'ALL',
      positionFilter: 'ALL',
      clientOptions: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getClients()
    this.getTitles()
    console.log('this one shows only []: ' + this.state.clientOptions)
  }
  
  getClients = () => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/clients')
    .then((response) => {
      let clientObj = [{value: 'ALL', label: 'ALL'}];
      const clientOptions = []

      response.data.forEach(function (client, index) {
        clientObj.push({value: client.name, label: client.name})
      });
      clientOptions.push({'options' : clientObj});

      this.setState(prevState =>{
        return{
             ...prevState,
             clientOptions : clientOptions
        }
     })
     console.log('this one works: ' + this.state.clientOptions)
    });
  }
```

As requested the state passed on to the child:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main">
        <Header 
          clientOptions={this.state.clientOptions}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you post a code where you are passing it to child component

Comment: no need to add `...prevState` in the state update function. React does that for you.

Comment: @SM1105922 Sure, see added code.

Comment: @Sulthan strange I learned this method in a tutorial, is it something new?

Comment: `getClients()` (and probably `getTitles()`) are asynchronous. You're logging the value before the Ajax call has resolved. It works correctly, you just have to prepare for in the Header component that the prop will change when the data has finished loading.

Comment: or start off with `clientOptions: null` and put something like `if(!this.state.clientOptions) { return <div>Loading...</div>; }` at the start of the render method.

Comment: @GuyIncognito Thanks, you are right, it was the asynchronous part that made me confused... Thanks!

Comment: @C.Ronaldo That was always there. A lot of people use it that way. In your case you don't even use `prevState` and could simply use `this.setState({ clientOptions })`